# Why when I enter bad url wordpress doesn't return error 404

Tags: url-rewriting, 404-error

I have simple WordPress site on Apache. I've created a page for blog that the it URL is http://localhost/mystart/blog. My permalink settings is set as "Day and name".

The problem is when I enter bad URL and repeat the page name in URL like http://localhost/mystart/blog/blog/blog it doesn't return 404 page and returns http://localhost/mystart/blog.

What is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress will automatically try and guess what the correct URL is. You can disable the feature using the [Disable URL Autocorrect Guessing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-url-autocorrect-guessing/) plugin.